# Gallery crashed after taking photo (intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

After taking the picture and clicking the "submit" button the Gallery app crashes. How is this possible and how can I fix it? The gallery is never used explicitly in my app.

I used the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to launch the camera.
To save the picture to the file system I used the code provided here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Btw I am using a Motorola TC55 with Android 4.1 (API 16)

Code snippets:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager())    != null) {

        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            return;
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            if (HttpManager.isNetworkAvailable(getContext())) {
// Send the picture to the webserver (start AsyncTask)
            } else {
// Save the call to process it later
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are no logs available in the logcat, because my app isn't crashing.
The only lines added in the logcat after starting the action are these:

```
07-29 08:57:13.081 31473-31473/com.test.test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

                                                                                    [ 07-29 08:57:13.081   180:  736 E/         ]
                                                                                    android::status_t android::QCameraStream_preview::getBufferFromSurface(): idx = 3, fd = 82, size = 462848, offset = 0

                                                                                    [ 07-29 08:57:13.091   180:  736 E/         ]
                                                                                    android::status_t android::QCameraStream_preview::getBufferFromSurface(): idx = 4, fd = 88, size = 462848, offset = 0

                                                                                    [ 07-29 08:57:13.091   180:  736 E/         ]
                                                                                    android::status_t android::QCameraStream_preview::getBufferFromSurface(): idx = 5, fd = 94, size = 462848, offset = 0
```

Sometimes I just get this:

```
07-29 09:01:19.464 12604-12604/com.test.test W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: provide logs, please

Comment: upload logs and the code snipet where you create the intent and the onActivityResult method please.

Comment: code snippets added

Comment: You need to ad crash logs.

Comment: well dude.. without log data how can we check.. where the problem is or what the problem is..? your app is not crashing, its okay.. but that doesn't mean there is no log data.Restart your studio or eclipse and emulator and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the code from the sample project: [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/PhotoIntentActivity.zip)

I think the problem was that Android 4.1 is not fully compatible with the FileProvider. And thereby there was a fault while saving the picture in the file (in the Gallery application). The sample code doesn't use it (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Such problems occur when the input connection in the previous page(or class) has not been closed. Check whether you've closed the input connection in the previous class (by giving connection.close()).

This problem arises when you leave the activity and keep an HTTP connection open.

Comment: I closed (.disconnect()) the HttpURLConnection but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately